# Auto-filling the HTML input field with a C++ QString value

Tags: c++, qt, qwebengineview

I am finding the `'Sign in'` text on the QWebEnginePage and then auto filling in the emailId in the input field if the correct page is displayed.
The value of emailId is basically a QString.

```
QString emailId = "abc@xyz.com";
```

What I have uptil now is the following, when the correct page is loaded, the input field is traced but the actual issue is setting the `value = abc@xyz.com`. Is there a way to set value of the input to be equal to the QString value.
(I do not want to hardcode the value).

```
ui->webEngineView->page()->findText(QStringLiteral("Sign in"), QWebEnginePage::FindFlags(), [this](bool found) {
    if (found) {
       QString code =  QStringLiteral("document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].value = emailId");
       ui->webEngineView->page()->runJavaScript(code);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not just use [arg](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg) or concatenation?  `QString code =  QString("document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].value = '%1'").arg(emailId);`

Comment: @eyllanesc Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it. Took me a while to understand the .arg() syntax but IMO it's more readable compared to concatenation. So yeah, using it for my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @eyllanesc's comment the following worked for me:

```
QString code =  QString("document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].value = '%1'").arg(emailId);
```